# How can I echo characters before and after a string?

Tags: php, string

I'm familiar with some of PHPs string functions, however I can't seem to find the right one to do what I want. What I'm trying to accomplish is to echo 22 characters before and after a string that I find. I'm able to find the starting position of the string as well as the string length...I'm thinking that these might be useful to accomplish what I need to. For example, let's say I find the string "hello". I want to echo "This is an example of hello how are you doing????" Will substr() accomplish this?

```
$var2 = 'hello';
$startingpos = strpos($var1, $var2));
$strlength = strlen($var2);
```

UPDATE: I've found the solution to my problem: Please see the below:

```
$additional_length = 2;
$startingpos = strpos($var1, $var2));
$strlength = strlen($var2);
if (($startingpos - $additional_length) < 0)
    $start = 0;
else
    $start = $startingpos - $additional_length;
echo substr($var2, $start, ($strlength + (2* $additional_length)))
```

Comment: echo str_replace($var, 'This is an example of '.$var.' how are you doing????', $var);

Comment: `sprintf` or `vsprintf` anybody?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily set a constant inside your string, and then replace it with str_replace function.

For instance:

$results = str_replace("[FOUND]", "hello", "This is an example of [FOUND] how are you doing");

Working example:

function.onl/str_replace("[FOUND]", "hello", "This is an example of [FOUND] how are you doing");

[Demo](http://function.onl/str_replace(%22[FOUND]%22,%20%22hello%22,%20%22This%20is%20an%20example%20of%20[FOUND]%20how%20are%20you%20doing%22);)

Comment: Thanks. I'm all set on this issue.